# drawing 2 rectangles with gradient on the same view in IOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, linear-gradients

I can't manage to display 2 rectangles with gradients on the same view. My following code only shows the first rectangle. If I omit the rectangle1 in the code the rectangle2 is displayed. Only in combination it will only show rectangle1.

I like to display the blue rectangle1 ...

[image]

... and the red rectangle2 with different gradient ...

[image]

... at the same time.

I have the following code for this:

```
func draw_2_gradient_rectangles(){

    let locations: [CGFloat] = [ 0.0, 1.0 ]

    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    // first rectangle
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace,
        colors, locations)

    var startPoint1 = CGPoint()
    var endPoint1 =  CGPoint()
    startPoint1.x = 0.0
    startPoint1.y = 10.0
    endPoint1.x = 100;
    endPoint1.y = 10

    let rectangle_main1 = CGRectMake(CGFloat(15), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(100), CGFloat(30));
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle_main1);
    CGContextClip(context)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint1, endPoint1, 0)

    // second rectangle
    let context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let colors2 = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]
    let gradient2 = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace,
        colors2, locations)

    var startPoint2 = CGPoint()
    var endPoint2 =  CGPoint()
    startPoint2.x = 100;
    startPoint2.y = 10.0;
    endPoint2.x = 10.0;
    endPoint2.y = 10.9;


    let rectangle_main2 = CGRectMake(CGFloat(15), CGFloat(50), CGFloat(100), CGFloat(30));
    CGContextAddRect(context2, rectangle_main2);
    CGContextClip(context2)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context2, gradient2, startPoint2, endPoint2, 0);


}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any help ?

Comment: How about using one context instead of two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` does not create a context but just gives you a reference to the current one. 
This means `context` is the same as `context2`. And in `context` you clipped the drawing area so the next `CGContextAddRect` will draw outside the clipping area.

What you need to do is save the drawing state before each rectangle creation code with :

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
```

and restore it before doing the second rectangle code with

```
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

This will make sure the clipping area is reset before drawing the second rectangle. e.g:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
// Create rectangle1
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
// Create rectangle2
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Thank so much. Thats the solution.